# Converting SQL Server Dynamic Cursor to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing the result of a match between rows in two different tables. In table a lines are uniquely identified by column export_invoice_id and in table b records are uniquely identified by column import_invoice_id. In addition to these identifiying columns the tables both have a set of columns containing invoice header data.
I need to match the rows from these two tables

There is a job that goes trough records in tables a and b and creates a match score depending on how well any row of data in table a matches any row of data in table b. The result is stored in table matches. The table contains the export_invoice_id from table a, import_invoice_id from table b and a match_score indicating how equal the records are. The higher the match_score - the more equal are the records in the two tables.

Exsample of data in matches table:

> ```
> IMPORT_INVOICE_ID    EXPORT_INVOICE_ID    MATCH_SCORE    SORT_ID
> 0                        5117095              17            1
> 0                        5117096               9            2
> 0                        5117097               9            3
> 1                        5117096              17            4
> 1                        5117097              17            5
> 1                        5117095               9            6
> 2                        5117097              17            7
> 2                        5117096              10            8
> 2                        5117095               9            9
> ```

Column sort_id gives sorting order (SORT BY import_invoice_id, match_score DESC, export_invoice_id)

I want to delete rows from this matches table so that I am only left with the best matches of export_invoice id in table a with import_invoice_id in table b. Each import_invoice_id and export_invoice_id value can only be used once.

> ```
> IMPORT_INVOICE_ID    EXPORT_INVOICE_ID    MATCH_SCORE    SORT_ID
> 0                        5117095              17            1
> 1                        5117096              17            4
> 2                        5117097              17            7
> ```

To do this in SQL Server i have the following cursor that does what I want (note the CURSOR DYNAMIC):

```
DECLARE @ExportInvoiceId AS int;
DECLARE @ImportInvoiceID AS int;
DECLARE @SortId AS bigint; 
DECLARE Match_Cursor CURSOR DYNAMIC TYPE_WARNING FOR 
SELECT export_invoice_id, import_invoice_id, sort_id FROM matches ORDER BY sort_id
OPEN Match_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Match_Cursor INTO @ExportInvoiceId, @ImportInvoiceID, @SortId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM matches WHERE sort_id > @SortId AND(export_invoice_id = @ExportInvoiceId OR import_invoice_id = @ImportInvoiceId)
        FETCH NEXT FROM Match_Cursor INTO @ExportInvoiceId, @ImportInvoiceID, @SortId; 
    END; 
CLOSE Match_Cursor; 
DEALLOCATE Match_Cursor;
```

How can this be done in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

holy cow that was harder than I thought

The issue is that oracle does read consistency differently than sql server

it is hard to do it in a cursor because if you open the cursor that result set is not refreshed unless you reopen it after the delete

so -- try this, it is just a straight up delete, no cursor

```
 delete
 from matches a
 where (a.match_score,a.sort_id) not in (select max(b.match_score), min(sort_id)
                        from matches b
                        where (a.import_invoice_id=b.import_invoice_id
                        or a.export_invoice_id=b.import_invoice_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I can not get this to work. This leaves me with only one line (the one with the smalles sort_id). Reason must be that the query in the FOR part only gets evaluated at det start and is not - re-evaluated as we delete records in the LOOP. It is not required that I delete from the same table that I select from - as long as I end up with one table containing the pair of unique best matches. Instead of deleting rows in your query. I changed it to only update column 'deleted' from 0 to 1 - same result - all but first record got marked with 1 in column 'deleted'